# Vue: Dropdown box in vue-select not showing value after selecting

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-select

I am populating a dropdown from a computed method that returns an array of store objects.  Then in the vue-select, I am passing this in as `options` and having the `option.address` show in the dropdown.  That is working as expected but when clicking a dropdown option, the box doesn't show the value -- it just remains blank.

```
computed: {
   storeLocationsArray: function() {
    let arr = [];
    this.storeLocations.forEach((location,index) => {
        arr.push({id: index, address: location.address})
    })
    return arr;
   }
}
```

```
<v-select
    v-model="selectedPickupLocation"
    :options="storeLocationsArray"
>
    <template class="single-option" slot="option" slot-scope="option">
        {{option.address}}
    </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: Your app will be throwing warnings ~ _"[vue-select warn]: Label key "option.label" does not exist in options object"_. You should [read the documentation](https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Basics/Options.html#labels)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `label` to display `address` instead of slot

```
<v-select
    v-model="selectedPickupLocation"
    :options="storeLocationsArray"
    label="address"
>
</v-select>
```